# Does mexopts.bat need a separate configuration when debug information is needed?

Tags: matlab, mex

I have written a `MEX` file which is successfully built in `MATLAB` `8.0.0.783 (R2012b)` under `Windows 7 64 bit` by:

```
mex -v mymex.cpp
```

However, when I want to add the debug information using:

```
mex -v -g mymex.cpp
```

I get the following error

```
mymex.cpp(28) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mkl.h': Invalid argument
```

Could someone help me why `mex` cannot find `mkl.h` when I am using `-g` while it works perfectly when `-g` is not used? I need to do this to be able to debug my `mex` code. All the necessary header and library files are accurately defined in `mexopts.bat`. I don't know why these options does not work for `mex -g` and does work when I am not using `-g` option.

Comment: What version of MATLAB?

Comment: It is 8.0.0.783 (R2012b).